# Facebook ios sdk disable ARC

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, github, automatic-ref-counting

I have a non-ARC project and i need to integrate Facebook SDK. As i understand, current version of framework (3.0.8) is to be used with ARC enabled. But i took a look at github master branch (actually both - master and preview) and... there are lots of retain/release/autorelease calls there and the project's 'Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting' is turned off.

So i guess, it doesn't support ARC from scratch and we need to run special script to build static library as **boz** [mentioned](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8421338/iphone-arc-facebook-sdk). But 1 - there's no such script there anymore, 2 - examples on the same branch of github use ARC! As for me - it's better just use non-ARC sources from github, but is it guaranteed that everything will work fine? It's weird: original github source code is non-ARC, but samples are ARC-oriented. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/lolgear/facebook-ios-sdk <- here you can see a script, that create a facebook-sdk (in *scripts* directory)

Comment: Thanks, but the question is not about that. By the way, there's no **build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh** under your link. It was either renamed either removed. The main i need to know: is ARC version of SDK built with previously mentioned script using these http://goo.gl/Ru6vk sources and i can just use these sources in my non-ARC app or it is a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook SDK whether your project is enabled for ARC or not. Just grab the SDK package from https://developers.facebook.com/ios (iOS dev center). Once you've downloaded and installed the SDK you can just follow the instructions in the Getting Started docs (under the iOS dev center) to set the SDK up.

Comment: C Abernathy, how are you going to use ARC code in your non-ARC app? if no release/autorelease massages sent inside SDK, there going to be lots of leaks. I'm not a noob, and not asking advices like 'how to google'. Instead, I need qualified comments about the situation.

Comment: Alex, as far as I know the Facebook SDK code is not ARC-based. The package that you download, once installed already bundles to code into a static library so you don't have to run any script and you can use the SDK whether your app supports ARC or does not. The samples released are all ARC based but I've run the SDK with a non-ARC project as well.